# Windows can't start from internal HDD but can if attached via an USB adapter

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, usb, sata

Hi I have the problem that Windows10 cant boot from my internal hard drive. Windows always displays that it was not shutdown properly and I have the option to trouble shoot in an advanced boot menu (like after pressing F8) or to restart. Neither helps and when restarting I will get the same message. However when I open my laptop and attach the hard drive via an Sata to USB3 adpater the message is displayed once and after a restart I can run Windows as usual.

This behavior is really unexpected. Of course I suspect the internal sata cable of having an issue, but I am not sure since I have no spare hard drive to test this behaviour on and also I am really curious how the cable could be damaged because the laptop was never opened before.

So my question is, how can this weird boot behaviour be explained?

Comment: Does it try to perform a start up repair when booting?

Comment: Yes sometimes, but I couldn't recognize a pattern yet

Comment: Sometimes it can take several startup repairs before it will boot successfully, use the advanced boot menu to do this.

Comment: It seems the repair isn't doing much. Some window flashes up then it says "Diagnosing your PC" then displays that the PC was not START correctly with the option to restart or to go into advanced boot menu. I clicked around and managed to start from the internal HDD via internal SATA in safe mode! After an error scan with no results and a restart I can now boot normally again! Thank you for the help!